# Animation Skipping to End of Desired Result

Tags: svg, svg-animate

Pen: https://codepen.io/jkmg/pen/zYKqvLq

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    html,body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: purple;
    }
    svg {
        height: 50px;
    }
    .playButton {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: white;
        display: inline-flex;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -50px;
        margin-top: -50px;
        border-radius: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .playButton .poscont {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .playButton .playGlyph {
        opacity: 1;
        margin-right: -5px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <span></span>
    <div class="playButton currentlyPaused">
      <div class="playGlyphPosition poscont">
      <svg class="playGlyph One" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 70.83 122.58">
        
        <path id="playPath" d="M20.55,119.08a11.89,11.89,0,0,1-20.3-8.35L0,61.29.25,11.85a11.89,11.89,0,0,1,20.3-8.34l45,45a18.11,18.11,0,0,1,0,25.62Z"> 
        <animate xlink:href="#playPath"
                 begin="indefinite"
                 id="pauseAni"
                 attributeName="d"
                 dur="1s"
                 fill="freeze"
                 attributeType="XML"
                 from="M20.55,119.08a11.89,11.89,0,0,1-20.3-8.35L0,61.29.25,11.85a11.89,11.89,0,0,1,20.3-8.34l45,45a18.11,18.11,0,0,1,0,25.62Z"
                 to="M20.55,109.49c0,15-20.3,15-20.3-.06L0,60,.25,10.55c0-14.06,20.3-14.06,20.3-.06l0,36.69c.31,7.31.31,16.31,0,25.62Z"
                 />
        </path>
      </svg>
        </div>
      
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.querySelector(".playButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
          if (this.classList.contains("currentlyPaused")) {
            this.classList.remove("currentlyPaused"); 
            this.classList.add("currentlyPlaying");
            document.querySelector("#pauseAni").beginElement();
            document.querySelector("span").innerText += "\nAttempted to play, ani to pause.";
          }
          else { 
            this.classList.remove("currentlyPlaying");
            this.classList.add("currentlyPaused");
            // document.querySelector("#playAni").beginElement();
            // this.querySelector(".playGlyph").classList.add("playing");
            document.querySelector("span").innerText += "\nAttempted to pause, ani to play.";
          }
        
        });
            </script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: gifforreference]

I'm attempting to animate a play button to a pause button and give the play button transformation to a faux line to use as an element for the pause button.

I have no idea why the animation is, animating with CSS or not, skipping to the end of the animation without actually "animating". Could someone please help me figure out what's going on?

Comment: If you want an animation to be smooth the from and to paths must contain the same commands. Yours don't. In one, the second command is an a, in the other it's a c

Comment: The finished product for those that want to know how it turned out: [https://codepen.io/jkmg/pen/zYKqvLq](https://codepen.io/jkmg/pen/zYKqvLq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll expand on Robert's comment.

The [SVG spec says](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#paths-TheDProperty):

> For animation, two d property values can only be interpolated smoothly
> when the path data strings contain have the same structure, (i.e.
> exactly the same number and types of path data commands which are in
> the same order). If an animation is specified and the lists of path
> data commands do not have the same structure, then the values must be
> interpolated using the discrete animation type.

However your two paths do not have the same structure.  The first path is:

**M** 20.55,119.08
**a** 11.89,11.89,0,0,1-20.3-8.35
**L** 0,61.29.25,11.85
**a** 11.89,11.89,0,0,1,20.3-8.34
**l** 45,45
**a** 18.11,18.11,0,0,1,0,25.62
**Z**

and the second is:

**M** 20.55,109.49
**c** 0,15-20.3,15-20.3-.06L0,60,.25,10.55
**c** 0-14.06,20.3-14.06,20.3-.06l0,36.69
**c** .31,7.31.31,16.31,0,25.62
**Z**

If you want to interpolate between the two paths, they'll need to have the same number and type of path commands.

In other words, you'll need to edit one (or both) so that they match.

Comment: To further a solution, would changing the path structure to match by simply editing the beginning variable of each point fix the issue?

Comment: If you mean the command letters (M, a, L, c etc), then no.  The commands mean different things.  M is move, L is line, a is arc.  You would need to edit those paths in a vector editor like Inkscape.  Work out which segment types you'll need (probably some combination of M, L and C), and how many. Start with one shape. Then adjust the points, to form the second shape, without adding or removing any,

Comment: Thank you! I was able to achieve the desired result and move forward with the animation. Thank you for your help. This was a great help in detecting what kind of point I was dealing with: [link](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/)

After being able to match the commands in a more ideal place, I ended up changing the animation type to spline to get a more controlled ease effect. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

> I have no idea why the animation is, animating with CSS or not,
> skipping to the end of the animation without actually "animating".
> Could someone please help me figure out what's going on?

As **@Robert Longson** commented and as illustrated in **@Paul LeBeau's** answer", the reason for the not smooth animation is due to the lack of requirements:

1. The number of node points in the initial `path` and in the final `path` must be the same. This requirement has been met.
2. Type of Nodes must be the same at the same positions in both paths

This requirement is not met

To fulfill these requirements for the start and end path, you can use the editing technique in a vector editor.

*Starting path*

[image]

*The final path*

[image]

It remains to copy these patches from the vector editor and add them to your code.

I have replaced the code of your script. You can probably use any script that performs trigger functions.

```js
var svg_1 = document.getElementById("svg1"),
  pause = document.getElementById("pause"),
  play = document.getElementById("play");

let flag = true;

svg_1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (flag == true) {
    pause.beginElement();
    flag = false;
  } else {
    play.beginElement();
    flag = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    html,body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: purple;
    }
    svg {
        height: 50px;
    }
    .playButton {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: white;
        display: inline-flex;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -50px;
        margin-top: -50px;
        border-radius: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .playButton .poscont {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .playButton .playGlyph {
        opacity: 1;
        margin-right: -5px;
        pointer-events:all;
    }
</style>
<div class="playButton currentlyPaused">
      <div class="playGlyphPosition poscont">
      <svg id="svg1" class="playGlyph One" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 70.83 122.58">
            
  <path d="m20.6 119.1c-5 5.3-20.3 2.2-20.3-8.3L0 61.3 0.3 11.9C0.3 1.3 15.4-1.2 20.6 3.5 26.3 8.8 29.4 12.3 35.8 18.9 43.7 26.9 50.8 35.1 58.7 42.7 73.9 57.3 74.6 64.7 59.1 80.7 52.6 87.5 46.5 92.5 36.1 103 29.2 110.1 27.5 111.8 20.6 119.1Z" style="fill:black;stroke:#000">
   
   <animate id="play" attributeName="d" dur="0.2s" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeType="XML"
    to="m20.6 119.1c-5 5.3-20.3 2.2-20.3-8.3L0 61.3 0.3 11.9C0.3 1.3 15.4-1.2 20.6 3.5 26.3 8.8 29.4 12.3 35.8 18.9 43.7 26.9 50.8 35.1 58.7 42.7 73.9 57.3 74.6 64.7 59.1 80.7 52.6 87.5 46.5 92.5 36.1 103 29.2 110.1 27.5 111.8 20.6 119.1Z" />
 
 <animate id="pause" attributeName="d" dur="0.2s" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeType="XML"
    to="M20.6 111C20.5 125.5 0.3 125.7 0.3 110.7L0 61.3 0.3 17c0-21.4 20.2-20.6 20.2-0.1 0 6.4 0 10 0 12.8 0 11.8 0.2 7.5 0.2 13-0.2 21.6-0.2 15.4 0 38.1 0.1 9.3 0.1 18.9 0 22.6-0.1 4.3-0.1 3.3-0.1 7.5z"/>
  </path>
</svg>
  </div>
      
    </div>
```